# Apply formula over Dataframe using row and columns values

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

this is a basic question. I have dataframe like:

```
          1000    4000   
index
 2000     NaN     NaN   
 4000     NaN     NaN
```

now I would like to apply a formula over the whole dataframe that could structurally look like this:

```
 cell_value = index_value + column_value
```

i.e. the NaN's in the Dataframe should be replaced by the formula.

What would be the most elegant way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could use apply

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(np.nan, index=[2000,4000], columns=[1000,4000])
df.apply(lambda x: x.name + x.index)
Out[15]: 
      1000  4000
2000  3000  6000
4000  5000  8000
```

since `apply()` return columns as `Series`  calling `x.name` returns the column name and `x.index`is self-explanatory

Comment: thanks @Steven G, this is the answer I was looking for. I was working on apply() but could not figure out how to address the columns/rows. x.name was the missing information.

Comment: @Al_Iskander glad it helped

Answer (score 4):

You can try something like this:

```
df[:] = df.index.values.reshape(df.index.size,1) + df.columns.astype(int)

df
#       1000    4000
#index      
# 2000  3000    6000
# 4000  5000    8000
```

Comment: this solves the question but for a way more complex formula instead of an addition this looks not applicable.